# render class overiding the class method in apiview

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a bit confused I want to render *HTML* or *JSON* by checking the accept header of the client but as I have specified the default render class,it is still rendering as per *render class* regardless of what *Accept header* is

```
class HomeView(APIView):
        template_name = 'blog_app/home.html'
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    
    
        def get(self,request):
            context = os.getcwd()
            print(request.headers['Accept'])
            if 'text/html'in request.headers['Accept']:
                
                return Response({'dir':context},template_name=self.template_name)
            else:
                return Response({'dir':context},content_type='json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `get_renderers` function.

```py
class HomeView(APIView):
        template_name = 'blog_app/home.html'
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]

        def get_renderers(self):
            if 'text/html'in request.headers['Accept']:
                self.renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
            else:
                self.renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
        return super().get_renderers()
    
        def get(self,request):
            context = os.getcwd()
            return Response({'dir':context})
```

Comment: this never came , thanks